# Can I install Ubuntu on a new model Mac Pro?

Tags: system-installation, macbook-pro

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a new model Mac Pro? The one that looks like a toilet brush holder. If so is it done in the same manner as the older models? Does anyone know what the performance will be like?

Thanks

Comment: `that looks like a toilet brush holder` < You get all of my what, sir.

Comment: I installed ubuntu on a macbook pro ... worked just fine ... once you burn the ubuntu install DVD just boot off it and pick the mode to test drive ubuntu without having to install to kick tires

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro

(Mac Pro - Cylinder), provided Apple has not released anything resembling a toilet brush holder, even more ;-).